# How automatically reject pull request if build failed in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops

How Can I automatically reject pull requests in Azure devops when a build has failed? I wont see  any pull request  in azure  if build is not succeed.i want to write a command for it in yamel file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is impossible to have the PR automatically rejected on a failed build but you can configure it so that the PR cannot be merged in until it does pass a build.

This is done by adding a build validation step in the branch policies. Documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)